# How do I concatenate strings with variables in PowerShell?

Tags: scripting, string, powershell

I'm trying to build a file path in PowerShell and the string concatenation seems to be a little funky.

I have a list of folders:

```
c:\code\MyProj1
c:\code\MyProj2
```

I want to get the path to a DLL file here:

```
c:\code\MyProj1\bin\debug\MyProj1.dll
c:\code\MyProj2\bin\debug\MyProj2.dll
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$buildconfig = "Debug"

Get-ChildItem c:\code | % {
    Write-Host $_.FullName + "\" + $buildconfig + "\" + $_ + ".dll"
}
```

This doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Be careful about using `Write-Host` - it *only* writes to the host console.  You can't capture that output into a variable.  If you simply remove `Write-Host` and have just the string sitting there it will 1) implicitly use Write-Output and 2) you will be able to capture that output to a variable e.g. `gci c:\code | %{$_.FullName+"\`$build-config\$($_.basename)\.dll"`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem  | % { Write-Host "$($_.FullName)\$buildConfig\$($_.Name).dll" }
```

In your code,

1. `$build-Config` is not a valid variable name.
2. `$.FullName` should be `$_.FullName`
3. `$` should be `$_.Name`

Comment: `$_.Name` includes the extension. I suspect the intent was to replace the current extension with `.dll` instead of tacking on an additional `.dll`.  :-)

Comment: He says he has a list of folders. So, $_.Name should be OK. Otherwise, $_.BaseName is OK.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the PowerShell equivalent of String.Format - it's usually the easiest way to build up a string. Place {0}, {1}, etc. where you want the variables in the string, put a `-f` immediately after the string and then the list of variables separated by commas.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\code|%{'{0}\{1}\{2}.dll' -f $_.fullname,$buildconfig,$_.name}
```

(I've also taken the dash out of the $buildconfig variable name as I have seen that causes issues before too.)

Answer (score 7):

Try the  Join-Path cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\code\*\bin\* -Filter *.dll | Foreach-Object {
    Join-Path -Path  $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath "$buildconfig\$($_.Name)" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get all dll files and filter ones that match a regex of your directory structure.

`Get-ChildItem C:\code -Recurse -filter "*.dll" | where { $_.directory -match 'C:\\code\\myproj.\\bin\\debug'}`

If you just want the path, not the object you can add `| select fullname` to the end like this:

`Get-ChildItem C:\code -Recurse -filter "*.dll" | where { $_.directory -match 'C:\\code\\myproj.\\bin\\debug'} | select fullname`